# Scope changes after ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I have a switch that changes the value of a variable called p.

```
<div ng-switch on="p">
   <div ng-switch-when="true">
       /*...show nodes and ability to add node*/
   </div>
   <div ng-switch-when="false">
       /*for now show nothing*/
   </div>
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.nodes=[{node1},{node2},{node3}];

function to add a node

$scope.$watch('nodes', function(nodes) {
    console.log(nodes); 
    console.log("================");   
},true);
```

**PROBLEM:** when i print $scope nodes in the above all the new nodes are shown. If I switch OFF and ON (p=false and then p=true) I have the initial $scope.nodes. Why on earth are my nodes reset on switch?
See this example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DwRvNSE9meagjFzRM1be?p=preview)

**EDIT:** ng-switch worked with no scope change if I didn't have a directive but reinitialized my scope when I used a directive inside it. Although I haven't understood exactly why I dropped ng-switch and used ng-show instead.

Comment: Can't understand, you are switching on `$scope.p` but you are watching `$scope.nodes`. When do you change `$scope.p`?

Comment: can you paste the code you are using to add nodes in html? and the function to add nodes

Comment: I have an on off switch like this one: https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/
The switch is done, I change views. The problem is why do my nodes change?

@akashrajkn the nodes change through a directive, that is why I skipped the function. Since my console.log shows that $scope.nodes are updated correctly why would a simple change of view reset them?

Comment: can you make a plunker or fiddle? mostly the problem is in the function to add node, but difficult to tell until you give more details

Comment: If the node is defined within the scope of the current view, switching view re-initializes a controller and thus the scope. That might be why the nodes are reset

Comment: @Guinn yes the node is defined withing the scope of the current view, but both views share the same controller.

Comment: It should not.  Something else is going on.  Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: If you, in the new view, use something like <div ng-controller="controller">, that very statement tells the app to re-initialize (or create a second scope) of that controller.

Comment: Guys my code is huge... I ll try to keep what's important to make a fiddle but till then can you think of any reasons this my happen? Thank you for all your answers

Comment: Sorry but that's not sufficient. You should try to post a smaller example of your code

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the controller and on which level it is initialized. The ngSwitch will not just **hide** the content - it will remove and add the html and initialize the controllers and directives each time a switch is made. Probably the nodes get initialized there as well.